# Post in group after import, only when field has same value

Tags: organic-groups, feeds

I have two contenttypes:
A which is a group-type
B which is a grouppost-type

Both grouptypes contain a similar field: color

All my group-posts will be imported using feeds and should then be posted into the groups.
HOWEVER only when the color field on both grouptypes contains the same value.

I am no php expert, can rules offer a solution for this usecase?

Thanks